Get real-time updates using gRPC server stream
I have two services that communicate with each other using gRPC. In a situation, service1 asks service2 for a camera list and this is by now a unary request. But the list can be changed during the time, even every month or many times in a single hour or never at all in a long period.
So to get these updates I think I have three simple solutions using the gRPC protocol.
1- Make the main procedure server stream instead of unary.
2- Service1 gives service2 another unary procedure to be called on changes.
3- Service1 calls service2 procedure (the origin procedure) periodically.
Although the gRPC server stream seems very good for this solution (as the real-time vehicle example mentioned in this article) and gives good cohesion to my code, I have some worries (as the real-time update rate is very low often):
1- Is memory usage of server streaming (keeping procedure scope live) efficient for this use-case?
2- Keeping the stream live (re-request after failure) takes resources. Is it OK again for this use-case?
3- Is it good to use the gRPC server stream for a lifetime (endless) running stream (getting real-time updates) at all, or it is designed for limited streams?

Your ask mutliple questions some of which require opinion-based including architectural-guidance responses. These are discouraged on Stack overflow. Using long-running gRPC streams adds some complexity in ensuring the underlying TCP connection is maintained. To be exhaustive, you could include inverting the flow and having the device with perfect knowledge of the cameras make the request against the list of subscribers. Your scenario is similar to load-balancing where servers come-and-go and this could be used as a pattern for your solution.
